# checking the position of an item in one list to another list

Tags: python, list, position

I am trying to make a trivia game, the only problem is I am having a hard time checking for the right answer. Here is my code for one of the questions

```
Question2 = random.choice(mylist)
print (Question2)
Userinput = input()
if(Question2.position == Question2answer.position):
    print('Yes, that is correct!')
else:
    print('Sorry, wrong answer')
mylist.remove(Question2)
```

I am trying to check if what the user put for question 2 was the answer to question 2 and not 4 by checking the positions in the list.

Comment: `enumerate` seems like what you want

Comment: Have you tried putting this data in a dictionary? It seems like it would be more suited for your purposes

Comment: What is Question2answer?

Comment: That is one of the things I can't figure out what to put. It needs to have the same position and Question2. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: do you want to check for existing of `user-input` in `question2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to use the right data type for the job.

For example, if your `mylist` were a list of `(question, answer)` pairs, instead of having two separate lists;

```
Question2, Answer2 = random.choice(mylist)
print(Question2)
Userinput = input()
if Userinput == Answer2:
    print('Yes, that is correct!')
else:
    print('Sorry, wrong answer')
mylist.remove((Question2, Answer2))
```

---

Or, alternatively, with a dictionary instead of a list:

```
Question2 = random.choice(mydict)
print(Question2)
Userinput = input()
if Userinput == mydict[Question2]:
    print('Yes, that is correct!')
else:
    print('Sorry, wrong answer')
del mylist[Question2]
```

Why is a dict better? Well, for one thing, with a list, you have to repeatedly search through the list to find the value you want—e.g., `mylist.remove` starts at the beginning and compares each element to your value until it finds the right one. Besides being slow, and overly complicated, this does the wrong thing if you can ever have duplicate values (e.g., try `a = [1, 2, 3, 1]`, then `value = a[0]`, then `a.remove(value)` and see what happens…).

---

But if you can't change the data structures, you can always use `zip` to zip up a pair of separate lists into a single list of pairs on the fly:

```
Question2, Answer2 = random.choice(zip(mylist, myanswers))
print(Question2)
Userinput = input()
if Userinput == Answer2:
    print('Yes, that is correct!')
else:
    print('Sorry, wrong answer')
mylist.remove(Question2)
myanswers.remove(Answer2)
```

Comment: I missed the need to remove the asked question.  dict is in fact better for that requirement as @abarnert pointed out.  +1

Comment: @sberry: You can still remove the asked question by using `enumerate` on top of `zip`, as one of the other answers does.

Comment: Oh sure, I know that.  I just prefer a dictionary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) as data container.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import random


Question = namedtuple('Question', ['question', 'answer'])
questions = [
    Question('Question 1', 'Answer 1'),
    Question('Question 2', 'Secret'),
    Question('Question 3', '3'),
]


q = random.choice(questions)
print("%s ?" % q.question)
user_input = raw_input().strip()


if(q.answer == user_input):
    print('Yes, that is correct!')
else:
    print('Sorry, wrong answer')

questions.remove(q)
```